# Why can't I check if a method returns true in my If statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors, boolean

What I am trying to achieve is that I want my if statement to check if my method verifyAnswer returns true, and if it does I want it to cancel my timer. So I searched up how to do the following but the answer I found all said similar things, however I think that since my argument in the method depends on a user answer it isn't working. This seems simple but I am new to Java and can't seem to make it work. Thank you all for the help!

```
public boolean verifyAnswer(String userAnswer) {
    
    
    String correctAnswer = this.questions.get(currentQuestionIndex).correctAnswerText;
    

    if(userAnswer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
        
        timer.pauseTimer();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Answer");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        timer.pauseTimer();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");
        return false;
    }
    
}    


Timer t = new Timer();
    
    int[] score = {0};
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(++score[0]);
            if (score[0] == 30) {
                t.cancel();
                
            }
            else if(verifyAnswer()) { //Why doesn't this line work?
                t.cancel();
            }
        };
    };
    
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 1000);
```

Below is a label with an action listener, so when the user clicks on it, it checks the text that is in the label with the verifyAnswer method to see if the user chose correctly.

```
    label_option_a = new JLabel("<html>Option A</html>");
        label_option_a.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            
        verifyAnswer(label_option_a.getText());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your `verifyAnswer` method has a string parameter, but you're not passing it any arguments. What do you expect the value of `userAnswer` to be, and why?

Comment: My verifyAnswer method checks if the user answers correctly between four wrong questions, so if the user answers correctly it should return true and vice-versa.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question though - where do you expect the user answer to come from? It's a method parameter, and you're not passing it in when you try to call the method.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to this so I don't really understand, when you say "where do I expect the user answer to come from", what do you mean exactly? I am not sure what argument I should be passing to make it work.

Comment: You should pass in "the user answer" - at the moment, we have no idea where that comes from. You haven't shown anywhere for the user to *supply* the answer. We don't know whether there's a field with that information somewhere, for example. How do you expect the user to provide the answer? How do you expect that information to flow through the program?

Comment: I think I understood it now, I have just edited my question with some extra information which I think is what you were looking for. The getText is acquiring the text from another method which holds the questions in case you were wondering.

Comment: Right - so can you call `verifyAnswer(label_option_a.getText())` from your timer task as well?

Comment: I can't, when I try doing it I get a nullpointerexception error. I'm sorry but I am really struggling to understand what argument I should use.

Comment: I'm afraid we can't really help you while we can only see bits of your code, and we don't know much about what you're trying to achieve. I suggest you use a debugger to work out why you're getting a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not passing an argument in `verifyAnswer` method. `verifyAnswer` expect string parameter.

```
public boolean verifyAnswer(String userAnswer) { .. }
```

You should call like this

```
else if(verifyAnswer("pass_what_argument_you_want_to_pass_for_user_answer")) { 
     t.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change true and false returns in your method. Like that

```
public boolean verifyAnswer(String userAnswer) {


String correctAnswer = this.questions.get(currentQuestionIndex).correctAnswerText;


if(userAnswer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
    
    timer.pauseTimer();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Answer");
    return false;
}
else {
    timer.pauseTimer();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Answer");
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: There's no indication that the OP wants the reverse result (I strongly suspect they don't) - and this doesn't address the problem of "the OP isn't passing in an argument for `userAnswer`"